# How to pass in IEnumerable object into HTML Extension and loop through it to find a property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Not sure if I'm making any sense, but I'm trying to practice on creating a custom html controls and for instance, say a GridView, I want to do

```
@Html.GridView(){
  DataSource      = model.Tasks, //or it can be model.AssignedTo, etc
  GridViewColumns = {
          new GridViewColumn(){Header = "Task ID", DataField= "ID"},
          new GridViewColumn(){Header = "Task Name", DataField = "Name")
          ..
  }
}
```

model.Tasks is a List of type Task.

First, what is the Type of "DataSource" property? Just `IEnumerable<T>`?

so how do I bind the DataField of GridViewColumn to the property of the IEnumerable? Like

```
foreach(var gridItem in DataSource)
{
        String dataField =  GridViewColumns[0].DataField;
        //??? gridItem.[??]
}
```

Not sure if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (dataSource is IEnumerable)
    foreach (object o in (IEnumerable)dataSource)
    {
       ... do something here

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Curt. So how do I bind the property say "ID" (which is a string) to the object o?

Comment: A string *is* an object.   You'll have to check the type of the object using object.GetType()  (since you won't know  the type beforehand of your datasource):  if it's a string, you can assign it by casting  (e.g. `string s = (string)o`).   If you'll only be *reading* from the dataset, you can probably take advantage of the fact that every object has a `.ToString()` method.

Comment: Curt. I think you misunderstood what I meant. The object o in reality is the type "Task" in my case. and Task object has a property called "ID" which is an integer.  DataField on the GridViewColumn object is a string and if I specifc ="ID". I want in reality be able to get the value of Task.ID, so I can output the value into an html td column.

Comment: @Liming You'll have to use Reflection to find the field, and then get the value.   Too complicated to put in a comment (it'll take code samples), but if you want, I could outline the approach in another answer...